# Is there a way to add a colour gradient number scale to Google Maps in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I have made a google maps activity and I am using a heatmap with a custom gradient scale. I would like to put a gradient number scale somewhere in the activity so that I can show the meaning of the colours in numbers, similar to the attached image. [image: heatmap with gradient number scale]

Is there a way to do this with the Google Maps SDK or do I have to do this another way>

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49467707/6950238) answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weighted heat maps in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465240/weighted-heat-maps-in-android)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it's not the heatmap that is my issue, I would just like to add the scale image to the activity somehow, which the arrow is pointing to in the above image

Comment: Anyway, you can show `ImageView` over map or something like that.